# regex match string replace in new string (notepad )

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

In Notepad++ I need to match "dog" (search) in

```
<tag>old-string/dog.swf">more-old-string</tag>
```

then use a back-reference (\1) to include it in another string (replace):

```
new-string_\1>more-new-string
```

to give the result

```
new-string_dog.swf">more-new-string
```

I'm new to regex, so please show me how to do this first by matching "dog", then by excluding all old-string in the result.

Edit: I realize this might be confusing, so I posted the actual problem here: [regex find word in string, replace word in new string (using Notepad++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915475/regex-find-word-in-string-replace-word-in-new-string-using-notepad). I hope it makes more sense.

Comment: do you have that input on its own line? otherwise how much should be included in `old-string` and `more-old-string`?

Comment: It's source-formatted html, so they're on separate lines. Old-string is 10+ lines. Same with new-string. I hope that's the answer you need.

Comment: I'm not sure. Do you only want to replace `/dog.swf` with `_dog.swf` or do you want to replace the stuff in front or after it with something else as well?

Comment: I want to find dog only, then use an entirely new string as the Replace, and put dog in that new string (new-string-dog-new-string). I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I made a new posting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915475/regex-find-word-in-string-replace-word-in-new-string-using-notepad

Answer (score 0):

I am totally going off a limb here trying to understand what you want, but if I have understood you correctly you want to:

1. match a certain word in one string
2. create a new string with data from the old one, under the old string which should be untouched

If so, this regular expression: `/^(.*?/([^"]+)\.swf)(".*$)/i` with this replacement: `\1\3\r\n<test>\2</test>` should do the trick. I have used `<test></test>` to show you where you put your "new-string" stuff.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much. I can't get it to work, though. I'm using The Regex Coach to play around with it, but I really feel like a monkey driving a spaceship.

Comment: I thought you were using Notepad++? In that case it should just be a copy/paste into the appropriate fields. Here's the regex explained: http://regex101.com/r/yB2nS5

Comment: I did check it in Notepad++ as well, but it says it can't find the text. I used old-string/dog.swf">old-string, and in "Find next" I put in /^(.*?/([^"]+)\.swf)(".*$)/i

Comment: @user1906842 Notepad++ does not use the slashes around the pattern. Neither does it have the `i` (case-insensitive) modifier in the pattern. That is done through the `Match case` checkbox

Comment: I made a new posting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915475/regex-find-word-in-string-replace-word-in-new-string-using-notepad